# How to map response to request when using "http-on-modify-request" and "http-on-examine-response"?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

How to map incoming responses to the outgoing requests when using HTTP observers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Setting_HTTP_request_headers#Observers ?

Comment: Just store the requests in an array as they go out and then use indexOf to figure out which one is which? I would guess that's what HttpFox does.

Comment: Looking into HttpFox source code: http://code.google.com/p/httpfox/source/browse/trunk/components/HttpFoxService.js Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 1):

Compare nsIHttpChannel objects, like [HttpFox](http://code.google.com/p/httpfox/source/browse/trunk/components/HttpFoxService.js) does:

```
getPendingRequestForRequestEvent: function(request) {
   // check for matching request
   for (var i = 0; i < this.Requests.length; i++) {
      if (request.HttpChannel === this.Requests[i].HttpChannel) {
         return i;
      }
   }

   // no match found
   return -1;
},
```