# Timing GET requests to a specific site

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I am trying to write a firefox plug in to record the time taken to serve all GET requests to a specific website. eg google and log this data to file.In other words I would like to use each GET request as an event to trigure a timer.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Do you want something like [this](http://figures.oreilly.com/tagoreillycom20090601oreillybooks300541I_book_d1e1/figs/I_mediaobject_d1e16958-web.png)? ([Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/pl/firefox/addon/firebug/) net panel)

Comment: Corresponding [source code](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/source/browse/branches/firebug1.9/content/firebug/net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to listen to the `http-on-modify-request` and `http-on-examine-response` notifications. These notify you [when a request is about to be sent and when a response has been received](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Observer_Notifications#HTTP_requests). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Setting_HTTP_request_headers for an example using `http-on-modify-request`, you would record the timestamp instead of setting a header. In addition, I guess that you will want to [get the tab that the request belongs to](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser#Getting_the_browser_that_fires_the_http-on-modify-request_notification). And finally, you match `http-on-examine-response` to preceding `http-on-modify-request` notifications by comparing their channel objects: [How to map response to request when using "http-on-modify-request" and "http-on-examine-response"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872773/how-to-map-response-to-request-when-using-http-on-modify-request-and-http-on-e)