# Firefox Extension Development: How to log every request's IP address?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, request, ip

I have some problems finding out, how to retrieve the IP address for **every** request(images, ajax, initial, etc.) of a webpage in a FF extension.
Just like it's done in Firebug.

What I tried:

[nsIWebProgressListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIWebProgressListener) just gives me the hostname for **one** request. With a dns lookup I am able to get the ip from the hostname.

[ServerSocketListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIServerSocketListener) looks like I have to open a Server Socket myself and ServerSocketListener is just listening on this Socket.

Is it at all possible?

If yes, which function shall I use?

Comment: How were you using `nsIWebProgressListener` that it only gave you one request?

Comment: I used onLocationChange only, cause it's the only function of nsIWebProgressListener giving me the hostname (nsIURI.host).

Answer (score 1):

You should be [using progress listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Progress_Listeners) for that. In particular, the important method to get all requests is `onStateChange`:

```js
const Ci = Components.interfaces;

...

onStateChange: function(webProgress, request, flag, status)  
{  
  if ((flag & Ci.nsIWebProgressListener.STATE_START) &&
      (flag & Ci.nsIWebProgressListener.STATE_IS_REQUEST) &&
      request instanceof Ci.nsIChannel)
  {
    // Request started
    var host = request.URI.host;
    ...
  }
},
```

See also [documentation on `nsIChannel`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIChannel).

The other option would be [using `http-on-modify-request` notification](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7510125/785541).

Comment: @user1252307: Feel free to test your code and find out what exactly doesn't work ;)

Comment: I wanted to write more, but hitting Return does not do a line break as expected but saves the comment :-(<br/>
<br/>
Here s the rest of my post:<br/>
<br/>
I am logging the hostname to the error console.<br/>
When I am surfing to y*hoo.com for example I get one entry: l.yimg.com<br/>
Firebug lists me about 15! requests.<br/>
I also tried to monitor an ajax request on: [http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_example.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_example.asp).<br/>
This is also not shown in my error console.

Comment: @user1252307: Added an alternative solution - that's the one Firebug is using. Maybe you have more luck with it.

Comment: That's working, thanks! I am using [Observer Notifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Observer_Notifications#HTTP_requests) now to listen to "http-on-examine-response". This gives me a [httpChannel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIHttpChannel) which gives me the "Host" header, which can be translated into an IP address with DNS.

Comment: We are doing this from a freamescript but its not catching ajax requests do you know whats up? Here is our code: https://github.com/Noitidart/Full-Stop/blob/master/resources/scripts/framescript.js that framescript is injected to the tab on button click: https://github.com/Noitidart/Full-Stop/blob/master/bootstrap.js#L91